# jquery.validationEngine with ajax php mail

Tags: jquery, validation

i am using http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/ for validtion and php for my mail but after long try i faild.. i am not so expart for thi.. any one can see where is my wrong..

my mail function ok if put php file inside action="process_demo-test.php" but if not.. then mail not send but validation work fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#contact_form").validationEngine({
                promptPosition : "centerRight",
                scroll: false,
                ajaxFormValidation: true,
                ajaxFormValidationURL: "process_demo-test.php",
                onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: function() {
                    $("#ajax").show();
                },
                onAjaxFormComplete: function() {
                      $('#loader').html("<p>Thank you!</p>")
                      .hide()
                      .fadeIn(1000);
                }
    });
});

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" class="general" method="post" id="contact_form">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="55%"><label for="company">Company Name <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="company" class="validate[required] text-input form-input" id="company" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="name">Contact Person <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="validate[required] text-input form-input" id="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="email">Email <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input form-input" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="email">Email Address<span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input form-input" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="tel">Telephone No <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="tel" class="validate[required,custom[phone]] text-input form-input"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="mobile">Mobile No</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-input"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="fax">Fax No</label>
        <input type="text" name="fax" class="form-input"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="address">Address <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="address" class="validate[required] text-input form-input"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="city">City <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="city" class="validate[required] text-input form-input"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="zip">Zip <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" class="validate[required] text-input form-input"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="country">Country <span>(required)</span></label>
        <select name="country" id="country" class="validate[required]">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select One </option>
          <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan </option>
          <option value="Albania">Albania </option>
          <option value="Algeria">Algeria </option>
          <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa </option>
          <option value="Andorra">Andorra </option>
          <option value="Angola">Angola </option>
          <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla </option>
          <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica </option>
          <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda </option>
          <option value="Argentina">Argentina </option>
          <option value="Armenia">Armenia </option>
          <option value="Aruba">Aruba </option>
          <option value="Australia">Australia </option>
          <option value="Austria">Austria </option>
          <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan </option>
          <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas </option>
          <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain </option>
          <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh </option>
          <option value="Barbados">Barbados </option>
          <option value="Belarus">Belarus </option>
          <option value="Belgium">Belgium </option>
          <option value="Belize">Belize </option>
          <option value="Benin">Benin </option>
          <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda </option>
          <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan </option>
          <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia </option>
          <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina </option>
          <option value="Botswana">Botswana </option>
          <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island </option>
          <option value="Brazil">Brazil </option>
          <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory"> British Indian Ocean Territory </option>
          <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam </option>
          <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria </option>
          <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso </option>
          <option value="Burundi">Burundi </option>
          <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia </option>
          <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon </option>
          <option value="Canada">Canada </option>
          <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde </option>
          <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands </option>
          <option value="Central African Republic"> Central African Republic </option>
          <option value="Chad">Chad </option>
          <option value="Chile">Chile </option>
          <option value="China">China </option>
          <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island </option>
          <option value="Cocos (Keeling Islands)"> Cocos (Keeling Islands) </option>
          <option value="Colombia">Colombia </option>
          <option value="Comoros">Comoros </option>
          <option value="Congo">Congo </option>
          <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands </option>
          <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica </option>
          <option value="Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)"> Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast) </option>
          <option value="Croatia (Hrvatska">Croatia (Hrvatska </option>
          <option value="Cuba">Cuba </option>
          <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus </option>
          <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic </option>
          <option value="Denmark">Denmark </option>
          <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti </option>
          <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic </option>
          <option value="Dominica">Dominica </option>
          <option value="East Timor">East Timor </option>
          <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador </option>
          <option value="Egypt">Egypt </option>
          <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador </option>
          <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea </option>
          <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea </option>
          <option value="Estonia">Estonia </option>
          <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia </option>
          <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"> Falkland Islands (Malvinas) </option>
          <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands </option>
          <option value="Fiji">Fiji </option>
          <option value="Finland">Finland </option>
          <option value="France, Metropolitan">France, Metropolitan </option>
          <option value="France">France </option>
          <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana </option>
          <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia </option>
          <option value="French Southern Territories"> French Southern Territories </option>
          <option value="Gabon">Gabon </option>
          <option value="Gambia">Gambia </option>
          <option value="Georgia">Georgia </option>
          <option value="Germany">Germany </option>
          <option value="Ghana">Ghana </option>
          <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar </option>
          <option value="Greece">Greece </option>
          <option value="Greenland">Greenland </option>
          <option value="Grenada">Grenada </option>
          <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe </option>
          <option value="Guam">Guam </option>
          <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala </option>
          <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau </option>
          <option value="Guinea">Guinea </option>
          <option value="Guyana">Guyana </option>
          <option value="Haiti">Haiti </option>
          <option value="Heard and McDonald Islands"> Heard and McDonald Islands </option>
          <option value="Honduras">Honduras </option>
          <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong </option>
          <option value="Hungary">Hungary </option>
          <option value="Iceland">Iceland </option>
          <option value="India">India </option>
          <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia </option>
          <option value="Iran">Iran </option>
          <option value="Iraq">Iraq </option>
          <option value="Ireland">Ireland </option>
          <option value="Israel">Israel </option>
          <option value="Italy">Italy </option>
          <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica </option>
          <option value="Japan">Japan </option>
          <option value="Jordan">Jordan </option>
          <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan </option>
          <option value="Kenya">Kenya </option>
          <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati </option>
          <option value="Korea (North)">Korea (North) </option>
          <option value="Korea (South)">Korea (South) </option>
          <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait </option>
          <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan </option>
          <option value="Laos">Laos </option>
          <option value="Latvia">Latvia </option>
          <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon </option>
          <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho </option>
          <option value="Liberia">Liberia </option>
          <option value="Libya">Libya </option>
          <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein </option>
          <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania </option>
          <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg </option>
          <option value="Macau">Macau </option>
          <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia </option>
          <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar </option>
          <option value="Malawi">Malawi </option>
          <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia </option>
          <option value="Maldives">Maldives </option>
          <option value="Mali">Mali </option>
          <option value="Malta">Malta </option>
          <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands </option>
          <option value="Martinique">Martinique </option>
          <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania </option>
          <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius </option>
          <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte </option>
          <option value="Mexico">Mexico </option>
          <option value="Micronesia">Micronesia </option>
          <option value="Moldova">Moldova </option>
          <option value="Monaco">Monaco </option>
          <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia </option>
          <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat </option>
          <option value="Morocco">Morocco </option>
          <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique </option>
          <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar </option>
          <option value="Namibia">Namibia </option>
          <option value="Nauru">Nauru </option>
          <option value="Nepal">Nepal </option>
          <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles </option>
          <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands </option>
          <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia </option>
          <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand </option>
          <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua </option>
          <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria </option>
          <option value="Niger">Niger </option>
          <option value="Niue">Niue </option>
          <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island </option>
          <option value="Northern Mariana Islands"> Northern Mariana Islands </option>
          <option value="Norway">Norway </option>
          <option value="Oman">Oman </option>
          <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan </option>
          <option value="Palau">Palau </option>
          <option value="Panama">Panama </option>
          <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea </option>
          <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay </option>
          <option value="Peru">Peru </option>
          <option value="Philippines">Philippines </option>
          <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn </option>
          <option value="Poland">Poland </option>
          <option value="Portugal">Portugal </option>
          <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico </option>
          <option value="Qatar">Qatar </option>
          <option value="Reunion">Reunion </option>
          <option value="Romania">Romania </option>
          <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation </option>
          <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda </option>
          <option value="S. Georgia and S. Sandwich Isls."> S. Georgia and S. Sandwich Isls. </option>
          <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis </option>
          <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia </option>
          <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines"> Saint Vincent and The Grenadines </option>
          <option value="Samoa">Samoa </option>
          <option value="San Marino">San Marino </option>
          <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe </option>
          <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia </option>
          <option value="Senegal">Senegal </option>
          <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles </option>
          <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone </option>
          <option value="Singapore">Singapore </option>
          <option value="Slovak Republic">Slovak Republic </option>
          <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia </option>
          <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands </option>
          <option value="Somalia">Somalia </option>
          <option value="South Africa">South Africa </option>
          <option value="Spain">Spain </option>
          <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka </option>
          <option value="St. Helena">St. Helena </option>
          <option value="St. Pierre and Miquelon"> St. Pierre and Miquelon </option>
          <option value="Sudan">Sudan </option>
          <option value="Suriname">Suriname </option>
          <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands"> Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands </option>
          <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland </option>
          <option value="Sweden">Sweden </option>
          <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland </option>
          <option value="Syria">Syria </option>
          <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan </option>
          <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan </option>
          <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania </option>
          <option value="Thailand">Thailand </option>
          <option value="Togo">Togo </option>
          <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau </option>
          <option value="Tonga">Tonga </option>
          <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago </option>
          <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia </option>
          <option value="Turkey">Turkey </option>
          <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan </option>
          <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands"> Turks and Caicos Islands </option>
          <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu </option>
          <option value="US Minor Outlying Islands"> US Minor Outlying Islands </option>
          <option value="Uganda">Uganda </option>
          <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine </option>
          <option value="United Arab Emirates"> United Arab Emirates </option>
          <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom </option>
          <option value="United States">United States </option>
          <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay </option>
          <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan </option>
          <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu </option>
          <option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State </option>
          <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela </option>
          <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam </option>
          <option value="Virgin Islands (British)"> Virgin Islands (British) </option>
          <option value="Virgin Islands (US)"> Virgin Islands (US) </option>
          <option value="Wallis and Futuna Islands"> Wallis and Futuna Islands </option>
          <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara </option>
          <option value="Yemen">Yemen </option>
          <option value="Yugoslavia">Yugoslavia </option>
          <option value="Zaire">Zaire </option>
          <option value="Zambia">Zambia </option>
          <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe </option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="refer">How did you know us ? <span>(required)</span></label>
        <select name="refer" id="refer" class="validate[required]">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
          <option value="Newsletter">Newsletter</option>
          <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
          <option value="Search Engines">Search Engines</option>
          <option value="Sales Respresentatives">Sales Respresentatives</option>
          <option value="Event/Exhibition/Flyer">Event/Exhibition/Flyer</option>
          <option value="Words of Mouth">Words of Mouth</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="option-group check" style="width:350px; margin-left:20px" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="cgrp" id="check1" class="validate[required] checkbox"  />
        <label for="check1" style="width:550px" >I have read the <a class="link" href="#">Reseller Agreement</a>, and i agree to all the terms there in</label>
      </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  ><input class="form-btn" type="submit" value="Submit Request" />
        <div id="loader"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Php code**

```
<?php 
$company = $_POST['company'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$address3 = $_POST['address3'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$alternatetel = $_POST['alternatetel'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$refer = $_POST['refer'];


$subject = $name;


$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Enquiry</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Request from $name</h2>
 <table width='95%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='11'>
    <tr>
      <td width='189'> Company Name :</td>
      <td>$company</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Contact Person :</td><td>$name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Email Address :</td>
      <td>$email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign='top'> Address :</td>
      <td>$address <br>
        $address2<br>
        $address3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City :</td>
      <td>$city</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Country :</td>
      <td>$country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zip : </td>
      <td>$zip</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Telephone No   : </td>
      <td>$tel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Alternate Tel No  : </td>
      <td>$alternatetel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Mobile No  : </td>
      <td>$mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fax No : </td>
      <td>$fax</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> How did you know us   : </td>
      <td>$refer</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "To:mailled@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$name."<".$email.">\r\n";


if(mail($toemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'We have received your request and will get back to you with further details shortly. check your mailbox for further updates.';
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending your email.';
}

?>
```

Comment: explain what problem u face it clearly

Comment: @TamilSelvan... i just update my post... after submit click nothing is happen . i mean mail not send and now successfull message show

Comment: still i am trying to fix

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

Comment: change to mail($toemail, $subject, $message, $headers) to mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)

Comment: don't use name="name"

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="process_demo-test.php" class="general" method="post" id="contact_form">
```